# Running tests and skipping some packages

Tags: go

Is it possible to skip directories from testing. For example given the structure below is it possible to test mypackage, mypackage/other and mypackage/net but not mypackage/scripts?  I mean without to write a go test command for each (
e.g. go test; go test net; go test other)

```
mypackage
mypackage/net
mypackage/other
mypackage/scripts
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Go test takes a list of packages to test on the command line (see `go help packages`) so you can test an arbitrary set of packages with a single invocation like so:

`go test import/path/to/mypackage import/path/to/mypackage/other import/path/to/mypackage/net`

Or, depending on your shell:

`go test import/path/to/mypackage{,/other,/net}`

---

You might be able to use interesting invocations of `go list` as the arguments (again, depending on your shell):

```
go test `go list`
```

Your comment says you want to skip one sub-directory so (depending on your shell) perhaps this:

```
go test `go list ./... | grep -v directoriesToSkip`
```

as with anything, if you do that a lot you could make a shell alias/whatever for it.

---

If the reason you want to skip tests is, for example, that you have long/expensive tests that you often want to skip, than the tests themselves could/should check [`testing.Short()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Short) and call [`t.Skip()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#common.Skip) as appropriate.

Then you could run either:

`go test -short import/path/to/mypackage/...`

or from within the `mypackage` directory:

`go test -short ./...`

You can use things other `testing.Short()` to trigger skipping as well.

Comment: I just want to skip one directory /package without to manually write ``go test packagex`` for each package I want to test.  Let's say you have 100 packages but you want to skip one . Does it make sense?

Comment: @mihai I added a go list |grep -v example; or you could arrange to have the tests in that sub-dir skip themselves unless some condition is set. Or you could re-structure your directories such that the "offending" one is elsewhere (if it really is somehow different enough from the others).

Comment: go test `go list ./... | grep -v directoriesToSkip` doesn't skip "directoriesToSkip" if they  are subdirectories of the current directory.

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat did you look at the output of `go list ./...` (or figure out/know what it does) before commenting? It lists *all* sub packages so as long as the regex matches any part of them then they will be skipped (due to `-v` inverting grep).

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment. I tried the command  but I've got an error from the directory I was trying to skip(that's the reason I was actually trying to skip it actually) thus the reason why I said it doesn't skips the directories.  Anyway I've fixed it with the -e flag and it's all fine.