# How can a test function be skipped on Github Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

There are some situations where some test cases should be (-for instance  a test requires to run VM and set some resources of that VM- ) skipped on CI, when Travis-ci is considered, we can add `tst.SkipCI(t)` at the beginning of function, then we are good to go. However, since Github announced its own CI [Github Actions], I want to use it for my test cases, but there is no way to skip a function from test file or I could not come cross with one of them. So, how it can be done on Github actions or can it be done on current version of Github actions ?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't set an environment variable in your workflow configuration and make your SkipCI function honor that?  Also, you haven't mentioned what language or environment you're using.

Comment: do you want to skip a whole step of the build (then conditionals is the answer) or what? what you do in the build: you start a test runner for an entire suite?

Comment: @bk2204 yeah true, I did not mention about environment, I am using go 1.13 and trying to test my test cases  for all operating systems [linux, windows, macos], but there are some functions which I want to skip on CI and do not glue how to do in github actions, is there any guideline regarding to it, because I could not find it.

Comment: @GiulioVian, No, I do not want to skip whole step of build, I just wanted to skip particular test functions in test file.

Comment: Than it depends on the test runner, not on the pipeline, if you are calling `go test` than this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064197/running-tests-and-skipping-some-packages